# How to design a popup div using JavaScript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I can use `window.open` to open a child window from the parent window. But I want the child window to stay on top and to disable the background and until and unless user selects anything from that window the child window won't get hidden. How to design that in JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: This is awfully broad - have you looked at Google for some possible answers?

Comment: The control i built using js, css and html is about 100 lines long with all code, total.. this is a bit broad. jQuery UI has a popup that accomplishes this. We used it and moved away from this because our custom script was more flexible and easier to control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is very broad, but I made a quick demo that might help you.

http://jsfiddle.net/VLNSP/

```
$('.pop').click(function(){
$('body').append('<div class="overlay"></div><div class="modal">Hi there. <a href="#"
class="ok">Ok</a></div>');
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.ok', function (event) {
    $('.overlay, .modal').remove();
});
```